CSS for different font size on each of 2 lines of text
I have 2 words that appear as 2 lines of text, eg. "Sports Warehouse" with "SPORTS" on line 1 and "WAREHOUSE" on line 2.  I am trying to recreate a logo with text in css where line 1 is font size 150px and line 2 is font size 100px.  The text is tagged H1. Can someone show me the custom CSS?
I am adding custom CSS to a section in shopify

What is the HTML?

How is the newline created - is it just a  after the Sports?

This should be a decent example.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You can achieve this by splitting the two words into separate elements and assigning each with an ID or class name. For instance:
<p id="sp">sports</p>
<p id="wah">warehouse</p>

Then, in your CSS, you can target these IDs to make the necessary adjustments:
#sp {
  font-size: 20px;
  /* Additional styles as needed */
}

#wah {
  font-size: 16px;
  /* Additional styles as needed */
}

Alternatively, if both words are within the same div element with an ID or class name, like spwah, you can use CSS to apply specific fonts or properties to each heading tag:
<div id="spwah">
  <h1>sports</h1>
  <h2>warehouse</h2>
</div>

#spwah h1 {
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
  /* Additional styles as needed */
}

#spwah h2 {
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', serif;
  /* Additional styles as needed */
}

Hope that helps :)


If I had to guess why your answer might have been downvoted, Your answer is poorly formatted, there are plenty of tools stackoverflow provides to offer proper syntax highlighting which would make your answer more clear. Good luck out there!

Thanks for the feedback, still trying to wrap my head around using the tools

It looks much better! Love the edit <3
